# Why the "presenceUpdate" does not working Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

`client.on("presenceUpdate", function (oldPresence, newPresence) { console.log(oldPresence, newPresence);   }`

This doesn't show anything on any logs even though no error shows up on logs
discordjs v12.5.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello there if your trying to set the bot's client presence then i would recommend to do the `client.user.setPresence` function and if you wanna console the clients status then you can do `console.log(status)`

```
 let status;
        switch (client.presence.status) {
            case "online":
                status = " Online";
                break;
            case "dnd":
                status = " Do Not Disturb";
                break;
            case "idle":
                status = " Idle";
                break;
            case "offline":
                status = " Offline";
                break;
        }
console.log(status);
```